# Python getting the last part after spliting with a dot

Tags: python

```
la = ["a.b.c.d", "a.b.c", "y.d.k", "z"]
a = []
for i in la:
    j = i.split('.')
    a.append(j[-1])
print a
```

shows d, c, k, z

I feel like getting `a` (a list of last part after dot from la) can be done in an one-liner. anyone have a better solution to this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
a = [x.rsplit('.', 1)[-1] for x in la]
```

Using [`rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with `maxsplit=1` (second argument) is more efficient if you are trying to get the element after the final separator.

Answer (score 2):

> getting a (a list of last part after dot from la) can be done in an one-liner. anyone have a better solution to this

Those goals might be at odds with one another.

But here's what you might be looking for:

```
>>> la = ["a.b.c.d", "a.b.c", "y.d.k", "z"]
>>> a = [f.split('.')[-1] for f in la]
>>> a
['d', 'c', 'k', 'z']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> la = ["a.b.c.d", "a.b.c", "y.d.k", "z"]
>>>
>>> [elem.split('.')[-1] for elem in la]
['d', 'c', 'k', 'z']
```

`li[-1]` access the last index of a list.

Comment: There's no need to split through the entire string.

Comment: @arshajii. Yeah right. But as alternative answers are already there, so I didn't edited.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [`str.rfind()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) with a slice here:

```
>>> la = ["a.b.c.d", "a.b.c", "y.d.k", "z"]
>>>
>>> [s[s.rfind('.') + 1:] for s in la]
['d', 'c', 'k', 'z']
```

I see no need to use `split()` or variations thereof here.

Looks like this is marginally faster than the most efficient split solution:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> 
>>> setup = '''
... la = ["a.b.c.d", "a.b.c", "y.d.k", "z"]
... '''
>>> 
>>> timeit("[s[s.rfind('.') + 1:] for s in la]", setup)
1.2622010707855225
>>> timeit("a = [x.rsplit('.', 1)[-1] for x in la]", setup)
1.6306350231170654
```

[@hcwhsa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255412/python-getting-the-last-part-after-spliting-with-a-dot/19255443#19255443) seems to confirm this.

Comment: Any reason not to use str.rindex()?

Comment: @wwii Yes, because that would raise an error if `.` is not found whereas `rfind` returns `-1`, resulting in the right answer.

Comment: +1 This is even faster than `str.rsplit` and deserves more upvotes than those `str.split` based answers.

Comment: @arshajii - I guess I was just wondering why you would want a result if an element doesn't have a ```.``` in it.  With a list comprehension though, you would loose the whole thing - you couldn't catch the exception and return results for *valid* elements.?

Comment: @wwii Well according to the OP he *does* want a result in such cases, namely the original string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
a = [i.split('.')[-1] for i in la]
```

Comment: There's no need to split through the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.rsplit` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x.rsplit('.', 1)[-1] for x in la]
['d', 'c', 'k', 'z']
```

`str.rsplit('.', 1)` will split the string only once at the last dot, so this will return:

```
>>> la[0].rsplit('.', 1)
['a.b.c', 'd']
```

Now you can use [-1] on this list to fetch the last item.

Using just `str.split`, will split at each `'.'`, which is inefficient and unnecessary.

```
>>> la[0].split('.')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

#### Timing comparisons:

```
>>> la = ["a.b.c.d"*10000, "a.b.c"*10000, "y.d.k"*10000, "z"*10000]*10000
>>> %timeit [s[s.rfind('.') + 1:] for s in la] #winner
1 loops, best of 3: 192 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [x.rsplit('.', 1)[-1] for x in la]
1 loops, best of 3: 750 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [f.split('.')[-1] for f in la]
1 loops, best of 3: 44.2 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new = [i.split('.')[-1] for i in la]
```